# On the derivation of Wess-Zumino term

Tags: string-theory, group-theory, wess-zumino-witten

$G$-$\text{WZW}$ model on a Riemann surface $\Sigma$ at the level $k$ is defined as

$${\displaystyle S_{k}(\gamma )=-{\frac {k}{8\pi }}\int _{\Sigma }d^{2}x\,{\mathcal {K}}\left(\gamma ^{-1}\partial ^{\mu }\gamma ,\gamma ^{-1}\partial _{\mu }\gamma \right)+2\pi kS^{\mathrm {W} Z}(\gamma )}$$

Where $S^{\mathrm {W} Z}(\gamma)$ denotes the Wess-Zumino term that ensures the conformal invariance of the theory at quantum scale. Can you explain how they found this term?

Comment: I don't how historically W and Z found this term. However, you can check yourself that the first term by itself is not invariant under gauge transformations $\gamma \to \gamma g$. You need to add the second term to ensure that the path integral measure $e^{ i S_k ( \gamma )}$ is gauge-invariant (when $k \in {\mathbb Z}$).

Comment: I meant, *I don't know...

Comment: In real life, the WZW term represents anomalous flavor chiral symmetries, deduced from anomaly consistency conditions in [1971](https://doi.org/10.1016/0370-2693(71)90582-X). Witten recast it in its modern topological form in [1983](https://doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213(83)90063-9), and then, shortly thereafter, introduced the analogous "deeper" (?) [2d form](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01215276).